# Mass-Energy-Space equivalence

Tags: electromagnetism, speed-of-light, mass-energy

If the speed of light in a vacuum is $c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\mu\epsilon}}$ and energy of mass at rest in a vacuum with no gravity is $E=mc^2$, shouldn’t $E=\frac{m}{\mu\epsilon}$ or $m=E\mu\epsilon$ be true? If so, does this represent an insightful relationship or am I being ignorant?

Comment: All these constants are but ratios between different units of measurement. In natural units, $E=m$ while $c=1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation is true but misleading. The relationship between mass and energy has nothing to do with electromagnetism; it is much more general and applies regardless of what forces are present. So expressing it using electromagnetic quantities conveys a false impression.

Yes, the $c$ in the formula is called “the speed of light”, and light is electromagnetic in nature, but this nomenclature is an unfortunate accident of history. Actually, $c$ should be thought of as “the invariant speed” and is related to the Minkowskian geometry of spacetime, which is a much more general concept than any specific force.

The general mass-energy-momentum relationship,

$$(mc^2)^2=E^2-(\mathbf{p}c)^2,$$

is today viewed as a geometrical statement about the Lorentz-invariant length of the energy-momentum vector $(E,\mathbf{p}c)$ in Minkowski space. This has nothing to do with electromagnetism or any other force. It is true in the absence of all forces.